# Android AdMobs problem

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to put in an ad but once the ad loads up, everything else in the program goes away leaving nothing but the ad.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"            android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
          <com.google.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="a14ddfjakd;fs;jds;jf4bd"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>  

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/item" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:scaleType="center"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you define your AdView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linearlayouts height is set to fill_parent and that causes a problem since it's parent, your scrollview, is also set to height:fill_parent.

Try this:

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/item" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:scaleType="center"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```