# Android AdMobs help

Tags: android, admob

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android AdMobs problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565133/android-admobs-problem)

I am trying to put in an ad but once the ad loads up, everything else in the program goes away leaving nothing but the ad. I know I am asking this again messed up the first time though please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"            android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
          <com.google.ads.AdView 
        android:id="@+id/adView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="a14ddfjakd;fs;jds;jf4bd"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>  

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/item" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:scaleType="center"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You posted the same question twice and marked an incorrect answer on the last one.  In the future, if you want to change something, you can always edit your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add android:orientation="vertical" to your initial LinearLayout tag.

The default orientation is horizontal which means the banner pushes the rest of your content off the screen to the side.